# What is an idiomatic way of executing code AFTER the QDialog is shown in PyQT?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside, qdialog

After a QDialog is shown using either `show()` or `exec_()` I need to add some additional widgets dynamically. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `show()` on your widgets:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import sip
sip.setapi('QString', 2)
sip.setapi('QVariant', 2)

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class testDialogs(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(testDialogs, self).__init__(parent)

        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.pushButton = QPushButton(self)
        self.pushButton.setText("Open a Dialog")

        self.pushButton1 = QPushButton(self)
        self.pushButton1.setText("Add a Text Edit")

        self.plainTextEdit = QPlainTextEdit(self)
        self.plainTextEdit.appendPlainText("This is a Widget")

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton1)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.plainTextEdit)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.on_pushButton_clicked)
        self.pushButton1.clicked.connect(self.on_pushButton1_clicked)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_pushButton_clicked(self):
        dialog = QDialog(self)
        verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(dialog)

        plainTextEdit = QPlainTextEdit(dialog)
        plainTextEdit.appendPlainText("This is a Dialog")

        buttonBox = QDialogButtonBox(dialog)
        buttonBox.setOrientation(Qt.Horizontal)
        buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        buttonBox.setObjectName("buttonBox")

        verticalLayout.addWidget(plainTextEdit)
        verticalLayout.addWidget(buttonBox)

        buttonBox.accepted.connect(dialog.close)
        buttonBox.rejected.connect(dialog.close)
        dialog.show()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_pushButton1_clicked(self):
        plainTextEdit = QPlainTextEdit(self)
        plainTextEdit.appendPlainText("This is another Text Edit")

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(plainTextEdit)
        plainTextEdit.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import  sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = testDialogs()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks for that, it helped a little. Could you show me some code on adding widgets AFTER a **QDialog** has been shown?

Comment: @liamzebedee `Qdialog` inherits from `QWidget`, as well as all other Qt user interface objects (`QMainWindow`, `QComboBox`, etc). You can run the script replacing `QWidget` with `QDialog`, or with any other widget that doesn't already have a layout